# Rails nested categories (Ancestry gem) - Dropdown select is not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dropdown, nested-forms, strong-parameters

All working fine except new or edited Adcategory is not saving to database. 
May be I'm missing something in the adcategories_controller strong parameters. 
Any help please?

[image]

#app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def nested_dropdown(adcategories)
result = []
adcategories.map do |adcategory, sub_adcategories|
    result << [('- ' * adcategory.depth) + adcategory.name, adcategory.id]
    result += nested_dropdown(sub_adcategories) unless sub_adcategories.blank?
end
result
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.select(:adcategory_ids, nested_dropdown(Adcategory.all.arrange), prompt: "Adcategory", selected: @adcategory ) %>
```

adcategories_controller.rb

```
def new
@adcategory = Adcategory.new
@adcategories = Adcategory.all
end

def edit
@adcategories = Adcategory.all
end

def create
@adcategory = Adcategory.new(adcategory_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @adcategory.save
    format.html { redirect_to @adcategory, notice: 'Adcategory was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @adcategory }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @adcategory.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

private

def set_adcategory
  @adcategory = Adcategory.find(params[:id])
end


def adcategory_params
  params.require(:adcategory).permit(:name, :parent_id, :adcategory_id )
end
```

Comment: Your select is named as `adcategory_ids` but you permit `adcategory_id`

Comment: Thanks, but adding ":adcategory_ids" in the ...permit, throws an error "unknown attribute 'adcategory_ids' for Adcategory"

Comment: Yes. I meant it has to be `adcategory_id` on form and in permit also. Why you called it in plural?

Comment: Ok, changing to adcategory_id in the form works for the drop-down select, but still throwing error after save "unknown attribute 'adcategory_id' for Adcategory"  No error when I remove adcategory_id from the strong parameters, obviously data will not save

Comment: Please post your adcategory model and adcategories table from schema